# Download Time Lapse Images in Python

Tags: python, image, web, download

I want to download a JPG image that is refreshed every 15 seconds in a web site to obtain a collection of files that can be later on assembled by a time lapse program for a video. I'm using Python ver.3 but I'm overwhelmed by the multitude of suggestions offered, opening and closing of files. Isn't there a simple command to fetch the file without opening it, and store it with an index in its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib.error
import urllib.request
import time

imageURL = 'http://YOUR-WEB-SITE.com/imageName.jpg'

directoryForImages = '/where/you/want/to/store/image/'
imageBaseName = 'basename'
extension = '.jpg'

maxLoops = 100

for imageNumber in range(0, maxLoops):
    try:
        # Open a file object for the webpage where you will get the image
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(imageURL)
        # Open the local file where you will store the image
        imageF = open('{0}{1}{2}{3}'.format(directoryForImages, imageBaseName, imageNumber, extension), 'wb')
        # Write the image to the local file
        imageF.write(f.read())

        # Clean up
        imageF.close()
        f.close()
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:   # The 'except' block executes if an HTTPError is thrown by the try block, then the program continues as usual.
        print "Image fetch failed.  Waiting another 15 seconds..."

    time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and report.

Comment: it works fine, thanks again. Now I need to figure out how to wait 15 seconds and loop incrementing the imageNumber. I do not understand the syntax of the open and format instructions though. Reading it in python.org didn't help either.

Comment: The `format` syntax is just a clean way of putting the content of variables together in a specified pattern to make a string.  Each of the `{0}`, `{1}`, etc are special markers that tell the `format` function where to insert the first, second, etc variable.  This one is pretty simple, and didn't really need the format string;  `'{0}{1}{2}{3}'.format(directoryForImages, imageBaseName, imageNumber, extension)` is equivalent to `directoryForImages + imageBaseName + imageNumber + extension`.

Comment: As for the waiting and looping, I added that in to the answer above.

Comment: it's working well, however, I need to handle an intermittent problem. From time to time the site is not able to provide the picture and the program stops Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Giovanni\Documents\Old PC\Personal\Giglio\GiglioNews\program to downlad pictures.py", line 21, in <module>
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(imageURL)... I truncated several error lines ...
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 595, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: You can solve that by adding error catching.  I modified the answer above - note that I had to import another module, then add a try/catch statement.  Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I made a refinement for the time elapsed.

Comment: I've expanded the code, with >1 feeds, delayed starts etc. One problem I'm experiencing is that one feed must be particularly prone to problems and eventually I receive the following error from that feed: line 76, in <module>
    imageF.write(f.read())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 515, in read
    s = self._safe_read(self.length)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 667, in _safe_read
    raise IncompleteRead(b''.join(s), amt)
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(368373 bytes read, 217344 more expected) - How to handle that exception please?

Comment: @gciriani This is a separate problem, so please ask this as a new, separate question.

Comment: Separate problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544510/python-http-exception-handling/18544532?iemail=1&noredirect=1#18544532