# Python HTTP Exception Handling

Tags: python, exception

I'm running a program that downloads files from a web sit. I've introduced one exception handling urllib.error.HTTPError, but now I'm getting from time to time additional errors that I'm not sure how to capture: http.client.IncompleteRead. Do I just add the following to the code at the bottom?

```
except http.client.IncompleteRead:
```

How many exceptions do I have to add to make sure the program doesn't stop? And do I have to add them all in the same Except statement or in several Except statements.

```
try:
   # Open a file object for the webpage 
   f = urllib.request.urlopen(imageURL)
   # Open the local file where you will store the image
   imageF = open('{0}{1}{2}{3}'.format(dirImages, imageName, imageNumber, extension), 'wb')
   # Write the image to the local file
   imageF.write(f.read())
   # Clean up
   imageF.close()
   f.close()

except urllib.error.HTTPError: # The 'except' block executes if an HTTPError is thrown by the try block, then the program continues as usual.
   print ("Image fetch failed.")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add individual `except` clauses if you want to handle each exception type separately, or you could put them all in one:

```
except (urllib.error.HTTPError, http.client.IncompleteRead):
```

You can also add a generic clause that will catch anything not handled previously:

```
except Exception:
```

For more informative messages, you can print the actual exception that happens:

```
except Exception as x:
    print(x)
```

Comment: thanks. What will happen if the exception was caused by an inability to close the file or download the file, or other mishaps? Should I try to close the file as part of the code immediately following the except statement?

Comment: @gciriani: You can use the `finally` clause to help ensure files are closed, or use the [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) which is a nicer way of doing that.